# start event when scrollTop is between a number and only fire one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ive a long scrolling page with lots of div layers. i would like to fire an event if i scroll between two numbers. variable only_once is for stopping after the first event, that it does not fire again and again between these numbers
eg

```
var only_once = 0
if(scrollTop("between 500 and 1000") && only_once == 0) 
{ fire me something one time; 
  only_once = 1};
```

any help is much appreciated. thanks ted

Comment: So you have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MwdwH/ and you want to fire events when the user scroll to another div?!

Comment: thats what i have already tried with waypoints, but i want to fire something when the user is directly linked to a div! the page loads and it starts an scroll 500, so this wont work...

Comment: Of course, it's not the solution I just ask what you want to do. I cant understand your question. Is that the layout you have?

Comment: yep it is! and when im clicking a link with an id, it refers to div 4 for example and there should be fired an event. one time!

Answer (score 1):

Use $.scroll() http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ , then use window.pageYOffset to get the current scroll position for the comparison.

Comment: and could you explain how i could do that? that would be nice!

Comment: I just updated Minko's jsfiddle with a couple lines of jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/MwdwH/1/